# Jekyll IF statement for 'IF index (home) and NOT paged'?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

As you may know Jekyll uses Liquid tags, and the Liquid templating engine has support for [`If / Else / Unless` statements](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#If_.2F_Else_.2F_Unless). Does anyone know how to show a specific content only on the 'homepage` (& NOT paged)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

---

***UPDATE:** This doesn't work, if you don't **yet** have enough posts for pagination. That is, it only works if you have at least `page1` and `page2`.*

As you may already know, [Jekyll supports pagination](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Pagination). So, to target just the Index/Home page (and specifically only the first page, i.e. `page1` and NOT `page2`, `page3` ...), you can use this:

```
{% if paginator.next_page == 2 %}

    <div id="welcome">Hello, welcome to my blog!</div>

{% endif %}
```

`{% if paginator.next_page == 2 %}` tells Jekyll to check if the next page of the pagination is `page2` (i.e. the current page is `page1`) and show the specified content.

---

**This works best of all:**

```
{% if paginator.previous_page %}
{% else %}

    <div id="welcome">Hello, welcome to my blog!</div>

{% endif %}
```

---

Untested, but `{% if paginator.previous_page == 0 %}` *might* work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to to is :

```
{% if paginator.page==1 %}
  // Do something here
{% endif %}
```